# file io .contains variable issue no output

Tags: java

First off, sorry about the formatting, i am a noob with all of this. i am trying to read through a list of doctor appointments based on names of patients, date, time, and doctor. my assignment is to read through the file and to display all of the appointments for that doctor. We did a similar assignment in class a week or two before, so i tried to base my work off of that, but it is not working. I do not get any output and i dont know why. if anyone could look at my code, that would be awesome, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class DocList

{

  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException

  {

    File file = new File("appts.txt");

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    String month;
    String day;
    String year;
    String militaryTime="";
    String doctor;
    long date=0;
    String nameDoc;
    System.out.println("enter doctor name: ");
    nameDoc = kb.nextLine();
    int sYear=0;
    int sMonth=0;
    int sDay=0;

    while(infile.hasNext())
    {
      name = infile.next();
      month = infile.next();
      day = infile.next();
      year = infile.next();
      militaryTime=infile.next();
      doctor=infile.nextLine();
      sYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
      sMonth= Integer.parseInt(month);
      sDay= Integer.parseInt(day);
      date = ((sYear*10000)+(sMonth*100)+(sDay));
      nameDoc=doctor;
      if(doctor.contains("myers"))
      {
      System.out.print(name+"\t");
      System.out.println(date);
      }
    getStandardTime(militaryTime);
    convertToLongDate(sYear,sMonth,sDay);

  }
  }

    public static String getStandardTime(String milTime)
    {
     int militaryHour = Integer.parseInt(milTime);
     int standardHour=0;
     String period = "";
     if((militaryHour>=12)&&(militaryHour<=24))
     {
       standardHour = militaryHour%12;
       period =standardHour +"pm";
     }else if((militaryHour<12)&&militaryHour>0){
       standardHour = militaryHour;
       period = standardHour+ "am";
     }
     return period;
    }
    public static long convertToLongDate(int m, int d, int y)
    {
      long date = ((y*10000)+(m*100)+(d));
      return date;
    }
}
```

[there's more to it, but it pretty much looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUiIK.jpg)

File contents

```
SMITH_ALBERT 10 1 2015 0900 Myers
SMITH_BRYAN 10 1 2015 0930 Myers
SMITH_LAURA 10 1 2015 1000 Myers
SMITH_AL 10 1 2015 1030 Myers
SMITH_HOPE 10 1 2015 1100 Myers
SMITH_JAMES 10 1 2015 1315 Myers
SMITH_JADA 10 1 2015 1330 Myers
SMITH_CODY 10 1 2015 1400 Myers
SMITH_PAUL 10 1 2015 1410 Myers
SMITH_PETER 10 1 2015 1430 Myers
SMITH_JANE 10 1 2015 1500 Myers
SMITH_LARRY 10 1 2015 1530 Myers
SMITH_COREY 10 1 2015 1600 Myers
SMITH_JON 10 1 2015 1630 Myers
SMITH_STEVE 10 1 2015 1700 Myers
SMITH_MATT 10 1 2015 0000 Myers
SMITH_SAMUEL 10 1 2015 0000 Myers
SMITH_PAM 10 1 2015 0000 Myers
SMITH_MILTON 10 1 2015 0900 Myers
SMITH_ROCKY 10 1 2015 0930 Myers
SMITH_JACK 10 1 2015 1000 Myers
JONES_ALBERT 10 2 2015 0900 Armstrong
JONES_BRYAN 10 2 2015 0930 Armstrong
JONES_LAURA 10 2 2015 1000 Armstrong
JONES_AL 10 2 2015 1030 Armstrong
JONES_HOPE 10 2 2015 1100 Armstrong
JONES_JAMES 10 2 2015 1315 Armstrong
JONES_JADA 10 2 2015 1330 Armstrong
JONES_CODY 10 2 2015 1400 Armstrong
JONES_PAUL 10 2 2015 1410 Armstrong
JONES_PETER 10 2 2015 1430 Armstrong
JONES_JANE 10 2 2015 1500 Armstrong
JONES_LARRY 10 2 2015 1530 Armstrong
JONES_COREY 10 2 2015 1600 Armstrong
JONES_JON 10 2 2015 1630 Armstrong
JONES_STEVE 10 2 2015 1700 Armstrong
JONES_MATT 10 2 2015 0000 Armstrong
JONES_SAMUEL 10 2 2015 0000 Armstrong
JONES_PAM 10 2 2015 0000 Armstrong
JONES_MILTON 10 2 2015 0900 Armstrong
JONES_ROCKY 10 2 2015 0930 Armstrong
JONES_JACK 10 2 2015 1000 Armstrong
WILLIAMS_ALBERT 10 3 2015 0900 Myers
WILLIAMS_BRYAN 10 3 2015 0930 Myers
WILLIAMS_LAURA 10 3 2015 1000 Myers
WILLIAMS_AL 10 3 2015 1030 Myers
WILLIAMS_HOPE 10 3 2015 1100 Myers
WILLIAMS_JAMES 10 3 2015 1315 Myers
WILLIAMS_JADA 10 3 2015 1330 Myers
WILLIAMS_CODY 10 3 2015 1400 Myers
WILLIAMS_PAUL 10 3 2015 1410 Myers
WILLIAMS_PETER 10 3 2015 1430 Myers
WILLIAMS_JANE 10 3 2015 1500 Myers
WILLIAMS_LARRY 10 3 2015 1530 Myers
WILLIAMS_COREY 10 3 2015 1600 Myers
WILLIAMS_JON 10 3 2015 1630 Myers
WILLIAMS_STEVE 10 3 2015 1700 Myers
WILLIAMS_MATT 10 3 2015 0000 Myers
WILLIAMS_SAMUEL 10 3 2015 0000 Myers
WILLIAMS_PAM 10 3 2015 0000 Myers
WILLIAMS_MILTON 10 3 2015 0900 Myers
WILLIAMS_ROCKY 10 3 2015 0930 Myers
WILLIAMS_JACK 10 4 2015 1000 Armstrong
DUNN_ALBERT 10 4 2015 0900 Armstrong
DUNN_BRYAN 10 4 2015 0930 Armstrong
DUNN_LAURA 10 4 2015 1000 Armstrong
DUNN_AL 10 4 2015 1030 Armstrong
DUNN_HOPE 10 4 2015 1100 Armstrong
DUNN_JAMES 10 4 2015 1315 Armstrong
DUNN_JADA 10 4 2015 1330 Armstrong
DUNN_CODY 10 4 2015 1400 Armstrong
DUNN_PAUL 10 4 2015 1410 Armstrong
DUNN_PETER 10 4 2015 1430 Armstrong
DUNN_JANE 10 4 2015 1500 Armstrong
DUNN_LARRY 10 4 2015 1530 Armstrong
DUNN_COREY 10 4 2015 1600 Armstrong
DUNN_JON 10 4 2015 1630 Armstrong
DUNN_STEVE 10 4 2015 1700 Armstrong
DUNN_MATT 10 4 2015 0000 Armstrong
DUNN_SAMUEL 10 4 2015 0000 Armstrong
DUNN_PAM 10 4 2015 0000 Armstrong
DUNN_MILTON 10 4 2015 0900 Armstrong
DUNN_ROCKY 10 4 2015 0930 Armstrong
DUNN_JACK 10 4 2015 1000 Armstrong
MARS_ALBERT 10 5 2015 0900 Myers
MARS_BRYAN 10 5 2015 0930 Myers
MARS_LAURA 10 5 2015 1000 Myers
MARS_AL 10 5 2015 1030 Myers
MARS_HOPE 10 5 2015 1100 Myers
MARS_JAMES 10 5 2015 1315 Myers
MARS_JADA 10 5 2015 1330 Myers
MARS_CODY 10 5 2015 1400 Myers
MARS_PAUL 10 5 2015 1410 Myers
MARS_PETER 10 5 2015 1430 Myers
MARS_JANE 10 5 2015 1500 Myers
MARS_LARRY 10 5 2015 1530 Myers
MARS_COREY 10 5 2015 1600 Myers
MARS_JON 10 5 2015 1630 Myers
MARS_STEVE 10 5 2015 1700 Myers
MARS_MATT 10 5 2015 0000 Myers
MARS_SAMUEL 10 5 2015 0000 Myers
MARS_PAM 10 5 2015 0000 Myers
MARS_MILTON 10 5 2015 0900 Myers
MARS_ROCKY 10 5 2015 0930 Myers
MARS_JACK 10 5 2015 1000 Myers
VENUS_ALBERT 10 6 2015 0900 Armstrong
VENUS_BRYAN 10 6 2015 0930 Armstrong
VENUS_LAURA 10 6 2015 1000 Armstrong
VENUS_AL 10 6 2015 1030 Armstrong
VENUS_HOPE 10 6 2015 1100 Armstrong
VENUS_JAMES 10 6 2015 1315 Armstrong
VENUS_JADA 10 6 2015 1330 Armstrong
VENUS_CODY 10 6 2015 1400 Armstrong
VENUS_PAUL 10 6 2015 1410 Armstrong
VENUS_PETER 10 6 2015 1430 Armstrong
VENUS_JANE 10 6 2015 1500 Armstrong
VENUS_LARRY 10 6 2015 1530 Armstrong
VENUS_COREY 10 6 2015 1600 Armstrong
VENUS_JON 10 6 2015 1630 Armstrong
VENUS_STEVE 10 6 2015 1700 Armstrong
VENUS_MATT 10 6 2015 0000 Armstrong
VENUS_SAMUEL 10 6 2015 0000 Armstrong
VENUS_PAM 10 6 2015 0000 Armstrong
VENUS_MILTON 10 6 2015 0900 Armstrong
VENUS_ROCKY 10 6 2015 0930 Armstrong
VENUS_JACK 10 6 2015 1000 Armstrong
SATURN_ALBERT 10 7 2015 0900 Myers
SATURN_BRYAN 10 7 2015 0930 Myers
SATURN_LAURA 10 7 2015 1000 Myers
SATURN_AL 10 7 2015 1030 Myers
SATURN_HOPE 10 7 2015 1100 Myers
SATURN_JAMES 10 7 2015 1315 Myers
SATURN_JADA 10 7 2015   1330 Myers
SATURN_CODY 10 7 2015   1400 Myers
SATURN_PAUL 10 7 2015   1410 Myers
SATURN_PETER 10 7 2015  1430 Myers
SATURN_JANE 10 7 2015   1500 Myers
SATURN_LARRY 10 7 2015  1530 Myers
SATURN_COREY 10 7 2015 1600 Myers
SATURN_JON 10 7 2015 1630 Myers
SATURN_STEVE 10 7 2015 1700 Myers
SATURN_MATT 10 7 2015 0000 Myers
SATURN_SAMUEL 10 7 2015 0000 Myers
SATURN_PAM 10 7 2015 0000 Myers
SATURN_MILTON 10 7 2015 0900 Myers
SATURN_ROCKY 10 7 2015 0930 Myers
SATURN_JACK 10 8 2015 1000 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_ALBERT 10 8 2015 0900 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_BRYAN 10 8 2015 0930 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_LAURA 10 8 2015 1000 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_AL 10 8 2015 1030 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_HOPE 10 8 2015 1100 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_JAMES 10 8 2015 1315 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_JADA 10 8 2015 1330 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_CODY 10 8 2015 1400 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_PAUL 10 8 2015 1410 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_PETER 10 8 2015 1430 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_JANE 10 8 2015 1500 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_LARRY 10 8 2015 1530 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_COREY 10 8 2015 1600 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_JON 10 8 2015 1630 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_STEVE 10 8 2015 1700 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_MATT 10 8 2015 0000 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_SAMUEL 10 8 2015 0000 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_PAM 10 8 2015 0000 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_MILTON 10 8 2015 0900 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_ROCKY 10 8 2015 0930 Armstrong
NEPTUNE_JACK 10 8 2015 1000 Armstrong
```

Comment: What's `appts.txt` look like?

Comment: @MadProgrammer added an edit

Comment: It would be helpful if we could copy and paste the text, that way we could debug your code on our machines

Comment: Remember, Java is case senstive, so `if (doctor.contains("myers")) {` should be more like `if (doctor.toLowerCase().contains("myers")) {`.  Also, you're ignoring the input from the user, reassigning, `nameDoc = doctor;`